# Why does this not insert?

Tags: python, csv, insert

I have a csv file with multiple columns, I want to add the contents of one column to the adjacent column if it is blank.

```
import csv
with open("new.csv", "r+b") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for rows in reader:
    if rows[4] == "":
        rows.insert(5,rows[3])
```

Comment: A reader does not write .. Check this post for reference; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978575/writing-reading-the-same-csv-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('i.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_list = []
    for rows in reader:
        sub_list = []
        for item in rows:
            # Replace even values by 0
            # This can be changed to do something else
            if int(item) % 2 == 0:
                item = 0
            sub_list.append(item)
        my_list.append(sub_list)       

print my_list
# output
#[['1', 0, '3', 0],
#[0, '3', 0, '5'],
#['5', 0, '7', 0],
#['9', 0, '11', 0],
#['13', 0, '15', 0]]

# Write the modified content to the same file
with open('i.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in my_list:
        writer.writerow(row)




# Read it to see if it worked
with open('i.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line

# output
# 1,0,3,0
# 0,3,0,5
# 5,0,7,0
# 9,0,11,0
# 13,0,15,0
```

The thing I did in that script is I replaced all the even number by 0, but you can simply changed them.