# Python for loop not running

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, for-loop

Im writing a simple command line program involving id's, i want to make it so that every time i run a function it should add a value to a CSV file. I have made a function that i thought worked, but apparently not. One of my for loops is not running correctly ;( Here is my code:

```
def addId(id):
    file = open(ID_FILE_PATH, 'wb+')
    read = csv.reader(file)
    write = csv.writer(file)

    existingRows = []
    existingRows.append(id)

    for rows in read:  # This does not run
        print rows
        if len(rows) > 0 and rows[0] not in existingRows:
            existingRows.append(rows[0])

    for rows in existingRows: # This runs
        write.writerow([rows])

    file.close()
```

Sorry for my bad English btw.

Comment: The problem is most probably that you're opening both a csv.reader AND a csv.writer on the same file object. See a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978575/writing-reading-the-same-csv-file-in-python).

Comment: Also, you shouldn't name the variable `file`, as this is a built-in data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open the file with:

```
file = open(ID_FILE_PATH, 'wb+')
```

[According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> note that 'w+' truncates the file

You truncate the file, so no wonder there is nothing to read in! Use `rb+` instead.